# Rsync remote path is read as a local path

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to upload a folder to my VPS. But when I run:

```
rsync -a --exclude=/node_modules ~/MyCoolProject/ root@X.X.X.X/:var/MyCoolProject
```

`X.X.X.X` being the IP address of my VPS. I get the following error:

```
rsync: mkdir "/Users/remi/root@X.X.X.X/:var/MyCoolProject" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

So it's looking for a `root@X.X.X.X` path on my local machine instead of connecting to the remote via SSH.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rsync -a ... root@X.X.X.X/:var/MyCoolProject
                         ^--remove
```

Remove the slash after "X.X.X.X". It's causing `rsync` to interpret the argument as a local directory instead of a remote directory.

Longer explanation: Rsync lets you specify a remote location using variations of the form:

```
user@host:/remote/directory
```

where *host* is a hostname or IP address. In your case, the "host" portion of your remote location is "X.X.X.X/". A valid hostname or IP address can't contain a "/", so rsync doesn't accept the argument as a remote location. Instead it falls back to interpreting the argument as a local directory name.